# SierpinskiTriangle() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)

Tags: python, class, object, initialization

I'm trying to initialize sT from an imported module. And getting the error:

```
sT = SierpinskiTriangle(self.dimensions, 50000, 0.5, vertices)
TypeError: SierpinskiTriangle() takes exactly 1 argument (4 given)
```

and I'm not really sure why or what I've done wrong.

```
sT = SierpinskiTriangle(self.dimensions, 50000, 0.5, vertices)
```

And I've imported this from another file:

```
 class Fractal(Canvas, Point):

    def __init__(self, dimensions, num_points, ratio, vertices):
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.num_points = num_points
        self.r = ratio
        self.vertices = vertices

    def frac_x(self, r):
        return int((self.dimensions["max_x"] - \
         self.dimensions["min_x"]) * r) + \
         self.dimensions["min_x"]

    def frac_y(self, r):
        return int((self.dimensions["max_y"] - \
         self.dimensions["min_y"]) * r) + \
         self.dimensions["min_y"]

def SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):

    def __init__(self, dimensions, num_points, ratio, vertices):
        Fractal.__init__(self, dimensions, num_points, ratio, vertices)
```

Edit, here's the Point class:

```
class Point(object):

    def __init__(self, x = 0.0, y = 0.0):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._y
    @y.setter
    def y(self, value):
        self._y = value

    def dist(self, secondPoint):
        #get the self x values from self.x and the values
        #of the seecond point from secondPoint.x
        #same with y
        dist = math.sqrt(((self.x - secondPoint.x)**2)+ ((self.y - secondPoint.y)**2))
        return dist

    def midpt(self, secondPoint):
        #same as the dist
        midpointx = (self.x + secondPoint.x)/2
        midpointy = (self.y + secondPoint.y)/2
        midpoint = Point(midpointx,midpointy)
        return midpoint

    def __str__(self):
        return "({},{})".format(self.x,self.y)
```

I hope this also helps clarify things. I don't have the Canvas class because it is a part of Tkinter.

Comment: could you share the Canvas and Point classes as well? My guess is you should pass a created Fractal instead of creating it inside SierpinskiTriangle

Comment: I can't post the Canvas class because it's from Tkinter. But I added the point class. 
It's required on the rubric for the class I'm in that there need to be subclasses for Fractal.

Comment: You have declared SierpinskiTriangle with the def keyword. You wanted the class keyword, I think.

Comment: could you post the whole code? what is vertices etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `def` instead of `class` for `SierpinskiTriangle` which means it only takes one argument (`Fractal`) instead of treating `Fractal` as its super class.

Change that to class like below and it will take 4 arguments.

```py
class SierpinskiTriangle(Fractal):

    def __init__(self, dimensions, num_points, ratio, vertices):
        Fractal.__init__(self, dimensions, num_points, ratio, vertices)
```